# How do I do a redirection in routes.rb passing on the query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I had a functioning redirect in my routes.rb like so;

```
match "/invoices" => redirect("/dashboard")
```

I now want to add a query string to this so that, e.g.,

```
/invoices?show=overdue
```

will be redirected to

```
/dashboard?show=overdue
```

I've tried several things. The closest I have got is;

```
match "/invoices?:string" => redirect("/dashboard?%{string}")
```

which gives me the correct output but with the original URL still displayed in the browser.

I'm sure I'm missing something pretty simple, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use request object in this case:

```
match "/invoices" => redirect{ |p, request| "/dashboard?#{request.query_string}" }
```

Comment: Thanks to answerer. Also be aware that this code not good from SEO side because if query_string will be empty, then url will looks like "...?"

Comment: In this case `match "/invoices" => redirect{ |p, request| request.query_string.blank? ? "/dashboard" : "/dashboard?#{request.query_string}" }` should do …

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to do this (at least in Rails 4) is do use the options mode for the redirect call..

```
get '/invoices' => redirect(path: '/dashboard')
```

This will ONLY change the path component and leave the query parameters alone.

Comment: Thank you!!! Went through about 6 different SO posts before I found this recent, simple one that solved all my issues.

Comment: Note that this does not forward params that are extracted from the path in the url like `invoices/:id`

Comment: @the_minted actually you can by simply using %{id}.  for examples `get '/invoices/:id' => redirect(path: '/new_invoices/%{id}')`

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works perfectly, it is not quite suitable for keeping things DRY — there is a lot of duplicate code once you need to redirect more than one route.

In this case, a custom redirector is an elegant approach:

```
class QueryRedirector
  def call(params, request)
    uri = URI.parse(request.original_url)
    if uri.query
      "#{@destination}?#{uri.query}"
    else
      @destination
    end
  end

  def initialize(destination)
    @destination = destination
  end
end
```

Now you can provide the `redirect` method with a new instance of this class:

```
get "/invoices", to: redirect(QueryRedirector.new("/dashboard"))
```

I have a written [an article](https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-preserve-the-query-string-when-redirecting-routes-in-a-rails-application) with a more detailed explanation.