# Rails routes redirect for query string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem, recently the name of a controller changed.

I changed the routes file to accept calls using the old controller name, for people with bookmarks referencing the old name:

```
get '/old/about', to: redirect('/new/about')
get '/old/report/:client', to: redirect('/new/report/%{client}')
get '/old/:sub_path', to: redirect('/new/%{sub_path}')
```

that works fine. But for calls with query string it blocks it to /report/200. for example:

/old/report/200?c_id=257&end=2013-10-19&num_results=294540&start=2013-10-13

it cuts the url to:

old/report/200

and shows me an error because of the lack of parameters. Do you know what can I do? (I thought the :sub_path line in the routes would help but not) :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039181/how-do-i-do-a-redirection-in-routes-rb-passing-on-the-query-string

Comment: I think you can be right, let me check it out, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question mention by Matt helped me to figure out my answer (thanks a lot!). It was a slightly different for my specific case. Im leaving the answer that worked for me for future reference.

```
match "/old/report/:client" => redirect{ |params, request| "/new/report/#{params[:client]}?#{request.query_string}" }
```

Comment: I would modify it a bit to check if request.query_string present as current solution always will add '?' to the bottom.

Answer (score 21):

Modify `redirect` to use the `path:` option to preserve the querystring:

```diff
- get '/old/about', to: redirect('/new/about')
+ get '/old/about', to: redirect(path: '/new/about')
```

This is demonstrated in the API docs for `redirect`, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html#method-i-redirect

Answer (score 3):

Building on Alejandra's answer, more verbose but without the `?` if there's no query string:

```
get "/old/report/:client", to: redirect{ |params, request| ["/new/report/#{params[:client]}", request.query_string.presence].compact.join('?') }
```

So `/old/report/:client?with=param` will become `/new/report/:client?with=param`,
and `/old/report/:client` will become `/new/report/:client`.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers work perfectly, but are not quite suitable for keeping things DRY — there is a lot of duplicate code once you need to redirect more than one route.

In this case, a custom redirector is an elegant approach:

```
class QueryRedirector
  def call(params, request)
    uri = URI.parse(request.original_url)
    if uri.query
      "#{@destination}?#{uri.query}"
    else
      @destination
    end
  end

  def initialize(destination)
    @destination = destination
  end
end
```

Now you can provide the `redirect` method with a new instance of this class:

```
get "/old/report/:client", to: redirect(QueryRedirector.new("/new/report/#{params[:client]}"))
```

I have a written [an article](https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-preserve-the-query-string-when-redirecting-routes-in-a-rails-application) with a more detailed explanation.